# How to get a working countdown timer with a button that adds +1 to a counter after every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting up a project for class which I need to use jquery. I have settled on a project whereby you would click the button, the counter would increase by one and a timer would start. This would act like a game to see how fast you can click in 10 seconds.

```js
$("#button").mousedown(function () {
score = score + 1;
startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
if (stop === 0) {
    stop = stop + 1;
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        counter++;
        display = 60 - counter;
        $("#button").html("Click! (" + display + " secs)");
        if (counter == 60) {
            alert("Times up!");
            clearInterval(interval);
            stop = 0;
            endscore = score;
            score = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicks">
   <p><span>0</span></p>
</div>
<div class="boxtext">
   <p>Time Remaining: <span>10</span> Seconds </p>
</div>
<div class="but">
   <button type="button" name="button">Click</button>
</div>
```

I expected the timer to start and the counter to increase by one but nothing happens at all.

Comment: There is no element with id="button", which is what `$("#button")` looks for.

Comment: And, instead of `mousedown`, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (JQuery deprecated the event shortcuts some years ago) and the `click` event. I sincerely hope your teacher didn't teach you to use that.

Comment: If this is your all code then `score` is not defined. Declare it in global scope otherwise error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var score=0;
var stop=0;
var counter = 0;
var endscore=0;
$("button").mousedown(function () {

score = score + 1;
$("#score").text(score);
startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
if (stop === 0) {
stop = stop + 1;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    counter++;
    display = 60 - counter;
   // $("button").html("Click! (" + display + " secs)");
    if (counter == 60) {
        alert("Times up!");
        clearInterval(interval);
        stop = 0;
        endscore = score;
        score = 0;
    }
    $('#timeRemaining').text(display);
}, 1000);
}
};
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clicks">
<p><span id="score">0</span></p>
</div>
<div class="boxtext">
<p>Time Remaining: <span id="timeRemaining">60</span> Seconds </p>
</div>
<div class="but">
<button type="button" name="button">Click</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

Add an id to your button:

```
<button id="button" type="button" name="button">Click</button>
```

Also you need to define the `score` & `stop` variables globally outside the function:

```
    var score = 0;
    var stop =  0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using as selector an ID, however your button element doesn't have that ID.  You can do the following:

- Add the id to that button.
- Or, you can change the selector as:

```
    $(".but").mousedown(function() { // or $('button[name="button"]').mousedown(function() {...});
      score = score + 1;
      startTimer();
    });
```

Comment: I think this is not the only problem. Because code still doesn't work.

Comment: @MaheerAli from the OP: *I expected the timer to start and the counter to increase by one **but nothing happens at all**.*  Now the OP should start to work on his/her approach.

Answer (score 0):

From your html you didn't have `id="button"` so use name selector or assign id to the button.

Like below.

```
$("input[name='button']").mousedown(function() {
  score = score + 1;
  startTimer();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize some variables and give some ids.

```js
var score = 0
var stop = 0

$("#button").click(function () {
score = score + 1;
startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
console.log('start timer')
if (stop === 0) {
    stop = stop + 1;
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('#interval')
        counter++;
        display = 60 - counter;
        $("#button").html("Click! (" + display + " secs)");
        if (counter == 60) {
            alert("Times up!");
            clearInterval(interval);
            stop = 0;
            endscore = score;
            score = 0;
        }
        
        $('#counter').html(counter)
    }, 1000);
}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicks">
        <p><span id="counter">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="boxtext">
        <p>Time Remaining: <span>10</span> Seconds </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="but">
      <button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: ***You forgot to initialize some variables and give some ids.*** << Well, which ones? A good answer should explain its solution. And please don't post links to Fiddles. You can just make a code snippet right here in your answer.

Comment: There's no need for a Fiddle.